# SOAP UI - Read the values of the row in the DataSource and get name of the property whose value is 0

Tags: groovy, soapui

Need help with groovy scripting to read the current row of the datasource and get the name of the property whose value =0.

considering the first row of the below datasource

---

drivers-licence-details proof-of-age-details passport-details medicare

1 1 0 0

1 1 1 0

---

the script should return

passport details & medicare

I would greatly appreciate if you could help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: What is a format of the data? Is it CSV?
Please let me know more details.

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489154/spreadsheet-parser-in-java-groovy

Comment: Also if you want you can send me sample document and I can try to work it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
def passport_details = context.expand('${dataSourceName#passport-details}' )
def medicare = context.expand('${dataSourceName#medicare}' )
```